# Unable to run buildr on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, buildr

I have Windows XP installed and I am trying to run buildr on it, I have never used Ruby before. I followed [instructions](http://buildr.apache.org/installing.html#windows) on the buildr website, i.e.:

1. Installed Ruby 1.8.6 for windows using [Ruby Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org)
2. Set JAVA_HOME env variable to point to my JDK
3. Ran the following: gem install buildr --platform mswin32. Seemed to install ok except for error about documentation (don't know if that is important or not):

> Fetching: rake-0.8.7.gem (100%)
>  Fetching: builder-2.1.2.gem
>   (100%)
>  WARNING: builder-2.1.2 has an invalid nil value for
>   @cert_chain
>  Fetching: net-ssh-2.0.23.gem (100%)
>  Fetching:
>   net-sftp-2.0.4.gem (100%)
>  Fetching: rubyzip-0.9.4.gem (100%)
>   Fetching: highline-1.5.1.gem (100%)
>  Fetching: json_pure-1.4.3.gem
>   (100%)
>  Fetching: rubyforge-2.0.3.gem (100%)
>  Fetching:
>   hoe-2.3.3.gem (100%)
>  Fetching: rjb-1.3.2-x86-mswin32-60.gem
>   (100%)
>  Fetching: atoulme-Antwrap-0.7.1.gem (100%)
>  Fetching:
>   diff-lcs-1.1.2.gem (100%)
>  Fetching: rspec-expectations-2.1.0.gem
>   (100%)
>  Fetching: rspec-mocks-2.1.0.gem (100%)
>  Fetching:
>   rspec-core-2.1.0.gem (100%)
>   *************************************************
>  
>    Thank
>   you for installing rspec-core-2.1.0
>  
>    Please be sure to
>   look at the upgrade instructions to see what might have
>    changed
>   since the last release:
>  
>   http://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Upgrade.markdown
>   
>   *************************************************
>  Fetching:
>   rspec-2.1.0.gem (100%)
>  Fetching: xml-simple-1.0.12.gem
>   (100%)
>  Fetching: minitar-0.5.3.gem (100%)
>  Fetching:
>   buildr-1.4.6-x86-mswin32.gem (100%)
>  To get started run buildr
>   --help
>  Successfully installed rake-0.8.7
>  Successfully
>   installed builder-2.1.2
>  Successfully installed
>   net-ssh-2.0.23
>  Successfully installed net-sftp-2.0.4
>   Successfully installed rubyzip-0.9.4
>  Successfully installed
>   highline-1.5.1
>  Successfully installed json_pure-1.4.3
>   Successfully installed rubyforge-2.0.3
>  Successfully installed
>   hoe-2.3.3
>  Successfully installed rjb-1.3.2-x86-mswin32-60
>   Successfully installed atoulme-Antwrap-0.7.1
>  Successfully
>   installed diff-lcs-1.1.2
>  Successfully installed
>   rspec-expectations-2.1.0
>  Successfully installed
>   rspec-mocks-2.1.0
>  Successfully installed rspec-core-2.1.0
>   Successfully installed rspec-2.1.0
>  Successfully installed
>   xml-simple-1.0.12
>  Successfully installed minitar-0.5.3
>   Successfully installed buildr-1.4.6-x86-mswin32
>  19 gems
>   installed
>  Installing ri documentation for rake-0.8.7...
>   Installing ri documentation for builder-2.1.2...
>  ERROR:  While
>   generating documentation for builder-2.1.2
>  ... MESSAGE:
>   Unhandled special: Special: type=17, text=""
>  ... RDOC
>   args: --ri --op C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/builder-2.1.2/ri
>   --title Builder -- Easy XML Building --main README --line-numbers lib
>   CHANGES Rakefile README doc/releases/builder-1.2.4.rdoc 
>   doc/releases/builder-2.0.0.rdoc doc/releases/builder-2.1.1.rdoc
>   --title builder-2.1.2 Documentation --quiet

1. Ran buildr --help and got the following error:

> C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in 'report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: buildr(1.4.6 not >= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
>           from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in 'activate_dep'
>           from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in 'activate'
>           from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in 'gem'
>           from C:/Ruby187/bin/buildr:18

I tried giving it a version:

> buildr _1.4.6 _ --help

But I just got the same error except for:

> 'report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: buildr(1.4.6 not =
>   1.4.6) (Gem::LoadError)

Has anyone else encountered this or am I doing something wrong?

thanks

**UPDATE:**
 I installed JRuby and that worked for me. Any feedback on the initial issue is appreciated, for now I am going to stick with JRuby.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BUILDR-580

The recommendation is *not* run `gem update --system`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is the same error I am getting except I never ran gem update --system.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Windows for Standalone and PIK installation.

```
pik install ruby 1.8.7
-- use it --
gem install buildr --platform mswin32 --no-rdoc --no-ri
C:/Users/yclian/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p352@java/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: buildr(1.4.6 not >= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from C:/Users/yclian/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p352@java/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
    from C:/Users/yclian/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p352@java/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
    from C:/Users/yclian/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p352@java/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
    from C:/Users/yclian/.pik/rubies/Ruby-187-p352@java/bin/buildr:18
```

Like the author said, JRuby is the workaround.

```
pik install jruby
-- use it --
jruby -S gem install buildr
buildr --help
 buildr [-f rakefile] {options} targets...
-- happy --
```